# Programmatically forward-lock an Android APK

Tags: android, copy-protection, apk

Doing a bit of advance research, and am stuck on the point summarized 
in the title. Namely, is there any way to forward-lock an APK 
installed programmatically, from another app? I've not come across 
anything beyond a hint in the following post: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/e39941389d4a4cf8

I can't see anything in the docs for PackageManager about forward- 
locking, but I readily confess that this is an unfamiliar area of the 
SDK for me.

[Cross-posted with the Android-Developers Google group]

Answer (score 3):

If anyone looks at this again... I've since found out that it can't be done in modern versions of the Android SDK. Plus, forward-locking has since been deprecated anyway.

Comment: You should answer your own question, if this answer is still valid.