# Android Apk Distribution

Tags: android, apk, distribution, google-license-manager

I have a question on the apk distribution. We all know that we can distribute apks through bluetooth, emails etc.

Now, when I download any apk from the google play, the app gets installed and that we cannot share it by using the licensing policies.

I have my apk on a website. I want the same thing. I want fresh installs from the website also. The app should not shared with any1.

Is there any way to this? Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: after installing of your app you can search and remove apk file.

Comment: You wont be able to stop users from getting the apk if you expect them to side load it. Deleting it is just going to anger them.

Comment: But wht if before installing the app, user distributes the apk?

Comment: @anuja you can not do that, there are other people also working to share apks :0, so u can just put efforts to delete it that what i can say.

Comment: @Mgamerz Its like not to try to put ur money in safe, else thieves gonna be more furious :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comment, You can not stop users to forward your apk if they have them in storage, what you can do is to delete it after your app installed, but it can be shared before installing.

and there are tools/apps exist in market which claim to convert installed app into apk, and then it can be forwarded to other device.

[Similar question on Forward locking of apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711298/programmatically-forward-lock-an-android-apk?rq=1)

**Edit :-** though you can not stop user to forwarding of your apk, But can stop other user to use it, if they receive this app from other sources then your web,   as I myself did it earlier, by client server communication where a key is getting generated on Server based on mobile IMEI, so this app is going to be activated for particular mobile based on IMEI number. hence if other users try to use it you can check if this IMEI is register or not, and take action accordingly.

Comment: Then it's tied to a single device. If a user buys an app and has multiple devices it's not going to run on all of them, only the first one.

Comment: @Mgamerz Yeah, there always limitations, And there always a solution :). though i used IMEI and didnt provided subscription for two phones, in this case instead of IMEI we can use gmail.

Comment: Hi @AAnkit How to restrict Android Apk Distribution. Can you explain me how to do it. Am struggling this concept. Thanks in adavnce