# How can I block my app from being available for sharing via Bluetooth or Wifi?

Tags: android, security, android-studio

How can I ensure that my Android application is not shareable via Bluetooth or Wifi? I also want that my app is install only via PlayStore and whenever it install on any device it will not extract back to apk for sharing or installing.

Comment: You can't prevent users from sharing your app.  This is a [huge problem](http://www.businessinsider.com/android-piracy-problem-2015-1) with no technical solution.  Big companies resort to legal solutions.

Comment: This has been covered many times before... unfortunately most of the answers posted over the years are mistaken in various ways but the linked question has one that is more or less right.  Fundamentally there are no actual *solutions* but anyone wishing to add a better *answer* should add it to an existing question, not yet another duplicate posting like this one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't prevent the apk from being shared as it resides in the data folder which can be retrieved using ADB.

A probable solution may be this answer, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14665858

Edit: As Chris pointed out, you don't even need to be rooted to get the apk, so removing that part.

Comment: Root is not required

Comment: Yes, correct. I just recalled that apps like `shareIt` can send the apks. Thanks for reminding.